# Did a man survive a 30mph fall from a tornado without breaking a bone because he was unconscious?

Tags: physiology

This [segment](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=WDNyozgky4s#t=6m30s) of the television show "Human Body: Pushing The Limits - Episode 1 - Strength" claims a person was sucked up by a tornado, and when he fell out of it he broke no bones because he was unconscious.

> One final twist saves Matt's life
>   something that allows his bones to use their natural strength to the maximum.
>
> As the storm hits, it hurls a lamp across the room, knocking Matt out cold.
>
> Matt's body goes completely limp. All his muscles are totally relaxed. This allows his bones to evenly absorb the shock of landing.
>
> "They said that if I was conscious then it would have hurt me more than it did. They said I was so relaxed, that's why I didn't get hurt as bad."

If  it is true where else is this phenomenon documented and how does it work?

Comment: A similar effect is that very small children or people who are drunk (and sometimes even people committing suicides) survive falls from surprising heights with surprisingly little injuries (Ref: http://www.cbdb.cz/kniha-18314-clovek-na-pokraji-svych-sil-clovek-na-pokraji-svych-sil).

Comment: @Oddthinking - the concept of drunks not breaking bones when falling from heights is a fairly common urban legend. I think this is merely a variation (with the same underlying mechanism at work, assuming it's true)

Comment: @DVK, so lets have a question quoting some people making that claim.

Comment: @Oddthinking - OK, if there's no such duplicate Q, someone should make it. it IS a nice skeptical claim.

Comment: The question seems irrelevant now ): unless Discovery made it up

Comment: @YUASK: Are you saying the description from the documentary is enough to satisfy you? Would you like to close the question?

Comment: No i added the where else is this phenomenon documented now its fine i think

Comment: Highly skeptical of this. I await the answer eagerly.

Comment: I also heard drunk drivers often survive car accidents where sober people are killed for the same reason.

Comment: **Did this really happen?** Is Matt's story documented in any other media? The lack of detail here leaves the consequences of "being sucked up by a tornado" to the imagination. Are we to think he fell from some great height or that he merely awoke rearranged in the rubble of his home?

Comment: @Suma There are stories of people surviving Skydiving when their parachutes fail. Bones are told to be stronger than concrete. though both of these seem to be skeptical claims on their own, searches reveal a lot of supporting results. Fainting goats kind of show off how relaxing in the right way can reduce injury, but to not break any bones at 30 mph is right on that line it seems.

Comment: I saw a news report (CNN or something like that) about a man who was lifted up by a tornado landed up a few hundred feet away and did not suffer any injuries. Here it is: http://abcnews.go.com/GMA/story?id=1749637

Comment: Also this article from NBC news: http://usnews.nbcnews.com/_news/2012/03/07/10592103-some-tossed-by-twisters-live-to-tell-about-it-but-how